# mail() headers not preventing mail going to junk mail folders

Tags: php, email, spam

im using these headers in my PHP to make sure that emails are avoiding the junk mail folder but they dont seem to be working very well.

```
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk <hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk <hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Return-Path: hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk <hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk>\r\n";
 $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n";
```

is there anythin from the above code that u would change or remover that might help this work?

Comment: moving away from mail() to something better, like swiftmailer or phpmailer, would be a good start.

Comment: im running out of time to be honest, i need something to work today, dont really have time to work out how these work

Comment: @GerryMckay It's a lot more likely to be the content of your message than the headers.

Comment: @gerry: phpmailer takes about 10 seconds to install and maybe 10 minutes to learn. if you're doing MIME mails and/or attachments, you'll probably REDUCE the amount of busywork code to just a few mailer calls v.s. acres and acres of pointless php.

Comment: Blindly adding headers with no understanding of what they mean is precisely what many spammers do. You are making your message look more spammy, not less.

Answer (score 2):

agreed with @MarcB: phpMailer is dead easy, and does all this stuff for you. Go [here](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) and download it. Then follow the examples [here](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicMail). You should be up and running in about ten minutes.

However, the really key point that should swing it for you is that you can tell phpMailer to send the mail via a different method to simply using PHP's `mail()` function.

Sending mail via your own PHP server is often the ultimate cause of the messages ending up being flagged as spam, because your PHP server is not recognised by the recieving mail systems as a legitimate source for email. So they assume it's spam. Systems like SPF and DomainKeys can be used to tell the world that your server is a legitimate server for email, but they can take time to learn and configure, and even more time for the message to get through to all the third party email servers out there.

With PHP's `mail()` function, you don't have a choice; the message is sent via your PHP server, and therefore unless you've got your domain configured very carefully, it can easily be flagged as spam.

But with phpMailer, it is possible to send via other routes, such as [your main SMTP server](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicSmtp), or even third party systems [like gmail](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicGmail).

Sending via a recognised email server like this will very likely solve your problems, but it can only be done with phpMailer (or a similar class), not with PHP's built-in `mail()` function.

Again, all of this is dead easy to configure with phpMailer.

You can spend a week bashing your head against a wall, another week setting up SPF and DomainKeys, and another month or two waiting for Hotmail and friends to start recognising your PHP server as a legitimate email source.... or you can spend ten minutes learning phpMailer and other ten or twenty mins re-writing your code to use it, have it send the mail via a known legitimate mail server, and have your emails accepted immediately. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding spam filters goes far beyond what headers you send with your emails. If your efforts stop with the code above you're going to find your level of success in avoiding spam filters to be so-so at best.

A few tips that you should keep in mind to help your mail avoid being marked as sapam:

1. Set up [DomainKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) for your domain
2. Set up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain
3. Put an unsubscribe link in your email
4. Set up Reverse PTR for your mail server's IP address

Comment: im the email there is a link with a random ID at the end so that it pulls out the relavant data from the database, coult this be causing the issue

Comment: Doubtfully. Spam filters are fairly robust and use many factors to determine the likelihood that a message is spam. That alone probably wouldn't be enough to put your mail over the top. Especially since it is common to use URLs in that fassion.

Comment: tiscali and hotmail accounts are the only ones not receive the email, i had tiscali working the other day and i think ive changed something without knowing and now its not working

Comment: the other question of course, is whether your email actually is spammy? That's not to say it's actual spam, but if people receiving it are flagging it as spam, their provider may be seeing that and increasing its spam score for all their users.

Comment: ive dont spam checked on the content and it seems fine... can understand why only hotmail is treating it as spam, so annoying... ive had a look at phpmailer, dont have a clue where to start with it. if anyone os free t help me with it id be much appreciated, ive got to get it working tonight

Answer (score -1):

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

will work on MSN or HOTMAIL